# CSS class properties not applied to react component

Tags: css, reactjs

I have the following react component:

```
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="TopBar">
        <div style={{ color: "green" }}>Rooms</div>
        <div>Chats</div>
        <div>User</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

However, the TopBar class in App.css:

```
.TopBar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-width: 1;
  border-color: gray;
}
```

seems to not be applied. The divs are showing in a column rather than a row. The border isn't showing either. How to fix this?

Comment: Did you try clearing cache ? or hard reload? Ctrl + Shift + R instead of just Ctrl + R ?

Comment: not enough debugging info; that should work

Comment: The code is working for me

Comment: Can you check the import location of the css file.

Answer (score 0):

For the border to render, you may need to first indicate the border style in your CSS. For example: `border-style: solid` or `border: 1px solid gray`.

Otherwise, your code should work. Here is a working sandbox using your code. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-component-styling-oy9m2